# How to reduce the unused space when Priority Inbox is empty in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, priority-inbox

When the Priority Inbox is empty I see this annoying message:

> Woohoo! You've read all the important messages in your inbox.

Is there an option or another way (working in Firefox possibly) automatically to remove that message?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Click on the section header (with the arrow at the end) and check **Hide section when empty**.

Comment: Brilliant -- I hadn't found that yet

Comment: I swear that option wasn't there when I first got PI...

Comment: Thank you very much, it was there and I didn't see it :)